# Problem with adding an array to the Local Storage by clicking on one of multiple buttons

Tags: javascript

I have 10 divs with 10 buttons inside (1 btn inside each div). The task is to add a div to the local storage by clicking on a button inside this div. (DIVS got via API)

I have the following code after the for loop that makes divs appear on the page:

`document.querySelectorAll(".watchList").forEach(button => { button.addEventListener("click", function() { localStorage.setItem("films", JSON.stringify(movies)) })`

This code doesn't work for some reason and the divs don't go to Local Storage on click.

Could you please help to find the bug here?

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you please provide more information? What are you actually trying to store, the HTML for the `<div>` elements? Or the text contained within the `<div>` elements? Or something else? The code you have provided doesn't give enough context.

Comment: I'm making a movie watch list. I got data via API. Made data appear on the page after putting the name of the movie. And then I want a movie to render on another page after clicking "+ add" button on 1 of the movies. I try to do it, but add btn doesn't work.

Comment: `container.innerHTML += <div class="movie" id="${movies[i].imdbID}">
  <div class="movieImg">
    <img id="poster"src="${movies[i].Poster}">
  </div>
  <div class="movieInfo">
    <div class="movieNameRate">
      <h3 class="movieName">${movies[i].Title}</h3>
      <p class="movieRate">${movies[i].imdbRating}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Details">
      <p class="movieTime">${movies[i].Runtime}</p>
      <button class="watchList" id="watchList"><img src="Icon +.png"> Watchlist</button>
    </div>
    <p class="movieDescription">
      ${movies[i].Plot}</p>
  </div>
</div>`

Comment: Here's the full code (only the main page): https://codepen.io/btb8293/pen/LYdvZVg?editors=1111

Comment: Please make edits to the question itself instead of adding new comments, it is hard to track code in comments

Comment: Your code doesn't work because `document.querySelectorAll(".watchList")` returns an empty array, but I don't know why as it is called after all `innerHTML` is set and insterted into the DOM.

Comment: It doesn't work because `document.querySelectorAll(".watchList")` is executed before the `innerHTML` is actually set. The `innerHTML` is being set by a `fetch()` promise, while `document.querySelectorAll(".watchList")` is executed immediately after the loop runs (but before the promise is returned). So you need to set the event listeners after all promises have completed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've added async/await and finally and things started working!